# How to fix resize for bmp file vertically, using array and fwrite?

Tags: c

I am writing code to make resize for BMP files. Some of the files are resizing correctly, but some of them no. What is my mistake?

I put original RGB to the array, already resize it horizontally, and try to fwrite array "n" times to outfile. Also, I put abs(biHeight) in case if it will be negative.

```
bi.biWidth*=n;
bi.biHeight*=n;
int padding1 = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
bi.biSizeImage = (bi.biWidth* sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding1) * abs(bi.biHeight);
bf.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding1) * abs(bi.biHeight);
int biWidth = bi.biWidth/n;
int biHeight =abs (bi.biHeight/n);
// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

//arrey for pic
RGBTRIPLE pic[biWidth*n];
// determine padding for scanlines
int padding = (4 - (biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;


// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0; i < biHeight; i++)
{
    int p=0;
    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < biWidth; j++)

    {
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple;


        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

        //conwerting to n pixels in scanlines
        for(int t=0;t<n;t++)
        {
            pic[p]=triple;
            p++;
        }
    }
    //writing pic for n
    for (int h=0;h<n;h++)
    fwrite(&pic,sizeof(pic),1,outptr);

    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

    // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
    for (int k = 0; k < padding1; k++)
    {
        fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }
}
```

I expect to get the correctly resized outfile image, but it is not working for all files
:) resize.c and bmp.h exist.

:) resize.c compiles.

:) doesn't resize small.bmp when n is 1

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 2

```
Byte 20 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0x00, not 0xff
```

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 3

```
Byte 29 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0x00, not 0xff
```

:) resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 4

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 5

```
Byte 47 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0x00, not 0xff
```

:) resizes large.bmp correctly when n is 2

:) resizes smiley.bmp correctly when n is 2

:) resizes smiley.bmp correctly when n is 3

Comment: The standard way to determine the scanline size is `(((bits) + 31) / 32 * 4)` with `bits` the number of of bits in a scanline.

Comment: Thanx, this is what do function "sizeof".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//writing pic for n
for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
{
    fwrite(&pic, sizeof(pic), 1, outptr);
    // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
    for (int k = 0; k < padding1; k++)
    {
        fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }
}
// skip over padding, if any
fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I remove function "fseek " from the brakes and it work!